# Task 'bootRepackage' not found in root project 'gateway'

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, jhipster

I am reading [Full Stack Development with JHipster](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/full-stack-development/9781788476317/) book.
I created a Microservice gateway with 'gateway' app name.
By following the book when I run

> ./gradlew bootRepackage -Pprod buildDocker

in the terminal, it says

> Task 'bootRepackage' not found in root project 'gateway'

and then stop running.
My Jhipster version is **5.0.0**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JHipster v5.0.0+, the goal `bootRepackage` doesn't exist. It has changed to `bootWar`, so you need to use:

```
./gradlew bootWar -Pprod buildDocker
```

Answer (score 4):

I have similar issue for Spring Boot 2.X. And solved it by changing to bootJar.

```
gradlew clean && gradlew bootJar
```